# Multiple taxonomy/term/% views

Tags: 7, views

I am using Views 3. is it possible to have multiple taxonomy/term/% view? That's because i need different theme for every vocabulary

Comment: You can clone the taxonomy term view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) and [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), this allows you to use different Views, and much for each vocabulary.

1. Enable the Page Manager and Panels.
2. Enable the term template
3. Create a variant of type "Panel", add to it a selection rule on the vocabulary.
4. Place View that you want to use in a suitable location.
5. Save

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for the [Taxonomy Views Integrator](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) module. It allows selective overriding of taxonomy terms and/or vocabulary with the view of your choice.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seems to do the override. Maybe I miss somthing..

Comment: worked for me! thanks for the reminder - it has been a long time since i faced this problem